# Concat parse results

Tags: haskell, parsec

I can create a parser which can handle two or three numbers, separated by comma, like this:

```
number :: Parser Int
number = many1 digit >>= return . read <?> "number"

numbers = do
  n1 <- number
  n2 <- char ':' >> number
  n3 <- optionMaybe $ char ':' >> number
  return ... -- return all of n1, n2, n3
```

Only the numbers are important, the rest can be discarded. Is there a way to concatenate the intermediate parse results (`n1,n2,n3`) to handle it outside of `input`? For example the parser-combinator of Scala can do this:

```
def numbers: Parser[Int ~ Int ~ Option[Int]] = // only the important numbers are returned
  number ~ (":" ~> number) ~ opt(":" ~> number)
```

I want to do this in order to pattern match the parser in different places. For example, in Scala I can do something like this:

```
val result = input.parseAs(numbers) {
  case n1 ~ n2 ~ None => // work with n1,n2
  case n1 ~ n2 ~ Some(n3) => // work with n1,n2,n3
}
```

where input is a string to parse. Does parsec have built-in functions to allow a similar behavior? If not how to built such a behavior by myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by using applicative functors. The pattern is generally:

```
import Control.Applicative

f <$> a1 <*> a2 <*> a3
```

`f` is some function that takes 3 arguments in this case, and `a1`, `a2` and `a3` are applicative functors over values that can be passed as arguments to `f`, for example if `f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Foo`, `a1, a2, a3` could have type `Parser Int`. The functors `a1, a2, a3` will be applied sequentially, and their results will be collected and mapped over the function `f`.

In your case, you'd want to do:

```
numbers :: Parser (Int, Int, Maybe Int)
numbers =
  (,,)
  <$> number
  <*> (char ':' *> number)
  <*> optionMaybe (char ':' *> number)
```

`(,,)` is the constructor of a 3-tuple, so it's a function taking 3 arguments and returning a 3-tuple. Passing 3 parsers with the `<$>..<*>..` pattern lifts the application of the 3-tuple constructor into the functor being used here, which is `Parser` in this case, so the whole expression returns the result of the mapped function wrapped in the functor, being `Parser (Int, Int, Maybe Int)`.

You can also use `liftA3 f a1 a2 a3` instead of `f <$> a1 <*> a2 <*> a3`; the two expressions are equivalent.

**PS.** You could define `number` using applicative functors, too (The monad interface is more "heavy-weight", and I personally try to avoid it):

```
number :: Parser Int
number = read <$> many1 digit <?> "number"
```